# Flutter: Increment a counter from 2 different classes with counter display on a common AppBar

Tags: flutter, class, flutter-layout, counter

I have a unique .dart page
At the beginning I would like to have a counter on a common AppBar, a "button 1" which allows to increment my counter, and another button which directs me to another class.
On this class, I would like to review the counter without it being reset to zero, it must keep the starting increment.
With the "button 2" which is in this new class, I would like to be able to continue to increment this same counter.

I have 2 problems (beginner):

1. the AppBar shows me an error for the counter
2. I can't increment from "button 1" and "button 2" which are
   in a different class from the counter. So I also have an error concerning these 2 buttons.

Can you help me by giving me a maximum of explanations please because I am new to Flutter.

Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class TestClass1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestClass1State createState() => TestClass1State();
}


class TestClass2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestClass2State createState() => TestClass2State();
}



class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  const Counter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  CounterState createState() => CounterState();
}



class AppBarShared extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor = Colors.red;
  final Text title;
  final AppBar appBar;
  final List<Widget> widgets;

  const AppBarShared({required this.title, required this.appBar, required this.widgets});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: title,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      actions: <Widget>[Counter()],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => new Size.fromHeight(appBar.preferredSize.height);
}



class CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 1;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child:Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}



class TestClass1State extends State<TestClass1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarShared(
        title: Text('title'),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        widgets: [this.widget],
      ),
      //backgroundColor: Color(0xffe80fd3),

      body: Container (

        child: Stack(
          children: [

            IconButton (
                iconSize: 40,
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_upward, color:Colors.amber)
            ),

            button1(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Container button1() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(

        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

        children: [
          IconButton (
              iconSize: 40,
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageRouteBuilder(
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => TestClass2(),
                  transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                ),
              ),
              icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_upward, color:Colors.amber)
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class TestClass2State extends State<TestClass2> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarShared(
        title: Text('title 2'),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        widgets: [this.widget],
      ),
      //backgroundColor: Color(0xffe80fd3),

      body: Container(

        child: Stack(
          children: [

            IconButton (
                iconSize: 40,
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_upward, color:Colors.amber)
            ),

            button2(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Container button2() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(

        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

        children: [
          IconButton(
              iconSize: 40,
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                PageRouteBuilder(
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => TestClass1(),
                  transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                ),
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward, color: Colors.amber)
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```